# Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I start my app I get a red error: **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** and in the analytics it says: Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10dc70598) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10dc708b8).
Code:

```
func fetchDataFromServer(callback: @escaping (Room) -> ()) {
    DataService.dataService.ROOM_REF.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        print("FOUND ROOM "+snapshot.key)

        let room = Room(key: snapshot.key, snapshot: snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
        callback(room)
    }
```

A bit of JSON:

```
{
  "rooms" : {
    "-LRjiSQjXY4OkfQLRpCZ" : {
      "caption" : "Potatis",
      "thumbnailUrlFromStorage" : "gs://ilapp-   a1429.appspot.com/KLabp9zlfgZZ78dPQ9Eysrc9C6r2/564386764"
},
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a snippet of the JSON under `ROOM_REF` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: If `let room = Room` is causing the crash, it means that `snapshot.value` is a `String`, not a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't see a export button for JSON in Firebase? If you mean the GoogleService-Info.plist there's nothing about ROOM_REF there.

Comment: @Larme I tried removing the dictionary to see if it was a string but then I got an error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>'

Comment: If you follow the link I gave, select a project, there'll be a `Export JSON` link in the overflow menu (⠇) of the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen oh thank you, found it! I've updated with some JSON.

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't see what's wrong there. Does the code print `FOUND ROOM -LRjiSQjXY4OkfQLRpCZ `?

Comment: yes, I kinda solved the error tho. Idk what was the problem but I just cleaned build the project and simulator also deleted everything from firebase database and storage. Somehow that worked! But thanks for the help anyways :D